# Why isn't the entered money incrementing onto the previous balance? (in Java)

Tags: java, currency, bank

I am creating a bankteller loop java code. I am trying to ask the user for what amount of money they would like to deposit into their account. I can get this to work once. For example, they will enter in $20 the first time. Then they will decide to put in $10 more. However, instead of displaying the current balance at $30, it only displays the one recently entered (the $10). How do I fix this?

Here is my code for that part of the loop in the menu that calls the class:

```
else if( userInput == 3 ){
            Account account = new Account();
            System.out.print("\nHow much would you like to deposit?: ");
            float money = input.nextFloat();
            account.deposit(money);
        }
```

Here is the code for deposit that is called:

```
public void deposit(float money) {
    if (money < 0) {
        System.err.println("Error: Can't deposit negative money.\n");
        return;
    }
    else {
        currentBalance = money + currentBalance;
        System.out.println("Current balance: $" + currentBalance + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Account account = new Account();` Don't create a new Account within the else if block. That variable is only visible within the block and no where else. Learn about variable scope.

Comment: Probably because it's creating a new `Account` instance every time, rather than reusing the instance.

Comment: avoid `float. use `double` unless you really know you need a `float. However using a floating-point type for money is a very bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You want to maintain the total balance so far. However, the moment you create a new `Account` object, balance gets initialized to zero and thus losing previous balance.
What you need to do is create an Account object only once and then call `deposit` on the same Account object.